# Erro na chamada de ZipArchive::close()

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Quando estou usando o método `close` para fechar a instância de `ZipArchive` estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Is a directory

O código da minha aplicação onde o `close` é executado é esse:

```
$solicitacoes = Remessa::with('solicitacoes')
                        ->findOrFail($id)
                        ->solicitacoes()
                        ->with('usuario')
                        ->get();

$zip = new \ZipArchive();

$zipName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'remessa_');

if ($zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {

    $filesWithProblems = [];
    $filesNormal = [];

    $dir = public_path('imagens');

    $remessaId = zero_fill($id, 4);

    foreach ($solicitacoes as $solicitacao) {


        if ($solicitacao->usuario->nivel_id == 12) {

            $filename = $dir . "/colaboradores/{$solicitacao->usuario->id}/{$solicitacao->foto}";
            $filenameInZip = "$remessaId/$solicitacao->foto";

        } else {

            $filename = $dir . "/{$solicitacao->usuario->matricula}/{$solicitacao->foto}";
            $filenameInZip = "$remessaId/$solicitacao->foto";


        }

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            $zip->addFile($filename, $filenameInZip);
            $filesNormal[] = $filename;
        } else {
            $filesWithProblems[] = $filename;
        }
    }
}


$zip->close();
```

Eu queria entender o que essa mensagem significa!

Comment: significa que é um diretorio, qual o conteudo da variavel `$zipName`? A pasta onde esta gravando o zip tem as devidas permissoes de escrita?

Comment: `$zipName` é um arquivo na pasta temporária criada por  `tempnam`. Só em uma remessa específica o problema ocorre. No resto funciona normal.

Comment: Quis dizer o conteudo mesmo, a string que ele esta gerando, tipo `remessa1.zip`, `nome qualquer.zip`. Se é somente em uma remessa especifica talvez nao seja algum arquivo comrompido/danificado que ta causando isso?

Comment: Achei isso em um comentario em outro post: `The message: [PHP Error] ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Is a directory --> the answer is simple, it is just because there was some symbolic link in the file tree`

Comment: Você só quer adicionar arquivos né? Ou pastas também, só para um teste tente trocar isto `if (file_exists($filename))` por isso `if (is_file($filename))`

Comment: Eu quero add arquivos. Adiciono um por um